# c# Create a class with a method that outputs title and author, create objects and call the method

Tags: c#, class, object, oop, methods

This is an assignment I have in c#:
"Create a class called Book that defines attributes Title, Author, and Year. Add a method called Display() that outputs the Title and Author. Demonstrate creating an object of type Book. Set some values to the attributes and call the Display() method that you created.

I have come up with something but I keep getting an error that "not all code paths return a value." This is the same error code that I kept getting on my last assignment as well but I don't know what it means. I just want to call my Display() method to show the title and author of one of my Book objects.

```
//filename: Book.cs
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Book 
  {
    string title;
    string author;
    int year;
    static string Display(string title, string author)//This is where the error message comes up
    {
    Console.WriteLine(title + " by " + author);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Book Lee = new Book();
      Lee.title = "To Kill A Mockingbird";
      Lee.author = "Harper Lee";
      Lee.year = 1960;

      Book Austen = new Book();
      Austen.title = "Pride and Prejudice";
      Austen.author = "Jane Austen";
      Austen.year = 1813;
      
      Book Orwell = new Book();
      Orwell.title = "Nineteen Eighty-Four";
      Orwell.author = "George Orwell";
      Orwell.year = 1949;

      Display(Lee.title, Lee.author);
      Display(Austen.title, Austen.author);
      Display(Orwell.title, Orwell.author);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: And change the method definition to this `static void Display(string title, string author)`

Comment: Since the return type of the method is `string`, you are supposed to call something like `return title + " by " + author;` in the method. If you don't want to do this, change the return type to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

```
static string Display(string title, string author)//This is where the error message comes up
    {
    Console.WriteLine(title + " by " + author);
    }
```

When you say `static string Display()` It’s telling c# that your method will `return` a string. This doesn’t mean to the console, it means it is sending it back to the program somewhere. Outputting to the console isn’t considered a return, it’s primarily used for debugging. The c# compiler is expecting a return statement somewhere, hence your error. If you would just like to print to the console without outputting a string, you can change the method’s return type to `void`. This tells c# that the method executes and no return is expected.

```
static void Display(string title, string author)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(title + " by " + author);
    }
```

If you WOULD like to return something, you need something like this. Note: it doesn’t look like you do in this scenario.

```
static string Display(string title, string author)
        {
            return title + " by " + author);
        }
```

Additional tip. Making the method static is doing a disservice to yourself. One of the powers of classes is that the can store data and then read from that data. Consider making your method not static so it can read directly from the stored fields. Then you won’t have to put any parameters in your method at all. This leverages the power of c#
Classes a bit better.